# Vertical text alignment in outlook not centering [with pictures]

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table, html-email

I'm currently trying to sort out some problems with a html email that renders fine in browsers and through gmail but unfortunately I'm having problems in outlook vertically aligning the text (it sticks to the bottom part).

This image shows you what's wrong:

[image]

```
<td align="center" style="font-size:17px;font-weight:bold;line-height:62px;"><a href="url" style="text-decoration:none;color:#000001;">THE WORLD'S BEST BRANDS</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="center"><a href="url" style="color:#000001;text-decoration:none;"><img src="url" alt="XXXX" width="593" height="100" class="brandsimage" style="display:block;border:0;" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>                                                
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="center" style="font-size:17px;font-weight:bold;line-height:72px;"><a href="url" style="text-decoration:none;color:#000001;">ESSENTIALS</a></td>
</tr>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add `valign="middle"` and a height to the `<td>` you want the text vertically centered on:

```
<tr>
  <td align="center" valign="middle" height="100" style="font-size:17px;font-weight:bold;line-height:72px;">
    <a href="url" style="text-decoration:none;color:#000001;">ESSENTIALS</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

In html email, always use,

`valign="top|middle|bottom"` for vertical alignment and

`align="left|center|right"` for horizontal alignment.

Just remember you need `height=""` or `width=""` set on the same `<td>` element.

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately no luck.

Comment: @user2619611 Get rid of your line height, it is pushing your text down.

Comment: Setting height, removing line-height and valigning has worked, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

For me to make it work, important was to specify `height` and `align="center"` as HTML properties and duplicate `height` in CSS `style` element.

```html
 

<td colspan="3" align="center" height="80px" width="100%"  
style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;
color:#666666;   height: 80px;   background: #cccccc;
padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
             <strong>for internal use</strong>
       </td>
```

Alignment issue was seen for all Word based Outlooks (2007 - 2016).