# HTML code does not show correctly on Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I had to put the text centered to the image, and it works everywhere except on Outlook desktop.
Does anyone know why this might be happening and what I could do to fix it?

The code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper" role="presentation" style="background-color: #EAE7DE; min-width: 100%; " width="100%">
 
  <tr>
   <td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner" style="padding: 0px 15px 15px; ">
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
     
      <tr>
       <td align="left" style="font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 20px; line-height: 1.5;">
        <font color="#454545" face="Neo Sans Pro, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"><span style="font-size: 19px;">lorum</span></font></td></tr><tr>
       <td align="left" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-top:10px;">
        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
         
          <tr>
           <td align="left" dir="ltr" height="8">
            <!--[if !mso]><!--><span style="display:block; background-color: #426e90;; font-size:0; border-radius:8px;height:100%;width:40px; max-height:8px;">&nbsp;</span> <!--<![endif]--> <!--[if mso]>
                                                                                        <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" fillcolor="#426e90;" style="top:1;left:1;width:40;height:8" arcsize="50%" strokecolor="#426E90" >
                                                                                        </v:roundrect>
                                                                                        <![endif]--></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr>
       <td align="left" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-top:10px;">
        <img alt="" data-assetid="1800" height="40" src="https://image.eu.email.maxi-cosi.com/lib/fe3111737364047f731173/m/1/0262ebcf-0222-4936-9a87-f5709e42741c.png" style="vertical-align: middle; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: 40px; width: 40px; border: 0px;" width="40">Revolutionary technology makes&nbsp;<br>
        <br>
        &nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
```

Here is what it (should) look like

[image: Preview]

What 'works' everywhere except Outlook is: `style="vertical-align: middle;`

I've also tried using the `float` property and `valign`

Comment: related, might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19981023/13927534

Comment: https://fullsphere.co.uk/html-emails/free-template/ try this..

Comment: @MissSkooter Didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is place the two contents into seperate columns and then you have better control over them. See code below:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper" role="presentation" style="background-color: #EAE7DE; min-width: 100%; " width="100%">
 
  <tr>
   <td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner" style="padding: 0px 15px 15px; ">
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
     
      <tr>
       <td align="left" style="font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 20px; line-height: 1.5;">
        <font color="#454545" face="Neo Sans Pro, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"><span style="font-size: 19px;">lorum</span></font></td></tr><tr>
       <td align="left" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-top:10px;">
        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
         
          <tr>
           <td align="left" dir="ltr" height="8">
            <!--[if !mso]><!--><span style="display:block; background-color: #426e90;; font-size:0; border-radius:8px;height:100%;width:40px; max-height:8px;">&nbsp;</span> <!--<![endif]--> <!--[if mso]>
                                                                                        <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" fillcolor="#426e90;" style="top:1;left:1;width:40;height:8" arcsize="50%" strokecolor="#426E90" >
                                                                                        </v:roundrect>
                                                                                        <![endif]--></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr>
       <td align="left" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-top:10px;">
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                <tr>
               <td align="left" width="40"><img alt="" data-assetid="1800" height="40" src="https://image.eu.email.maxi-cosi.com/lib/fe3111737364047f731173/m/1/0262ebcf-0222-4936-9a87-f5709e42741c.png" style="vertical-align: middle; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: 40px; width: 40px; border: 0px;" width="40"></td>
               <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 8px; line-height: 1.5;">Revolutionary technology makes&nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
               </table>
        
        <br>
        <br>
        &nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
```